# Android RecyclerView: how do I put data into a Fragment from the Adapter?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView list.  I am trying to set up an onItemLongClick method in the MainActivity to launch a DialogFragment.  The dialog will ask the user to confirm they want to delete an item in the RecyclerView list.  I want to capture the RecyclerView item's position from the Adapter file so that the fragment can delete the correct item from a SQLite database.

I am trying to pass the RecyclerView item position in a Bundle with setArguments.  Android Studio issues the following error on the "bundle.putInt" line: Wrong 2nd argument type.  Found: 'Contact' (my data model), required 'int'.  What am I missing here?

p.s. I also have an "onItemClick" method that correctly loads another Activity called "ActActivity" that is also shown below for reference.  Both the onItemClick and onItemLongClick are set up with a ClickListener interface in the Adapter file.  Both click methods were tested using Toasts and are working fine.

From Activity file:

```
...
@Override
public void onItemLongClick(int position, View view) {
    // For API >=14, use getFragmentManager() below.
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("item position", **contactListAdapter.getItem(position)**); // error here.

    android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    fm.setArguments(bundle);
    DeleteCardViewFragment delCardViewDialog = new DeleteCardViewFragment();
    delCardViewDialog.show(fm,"delcardview dialog");
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(int position, View view) {
    ActActivity.start(this, contactListAdapter.getItem(position)); 
}
```

From RecyclerView's Adapter file:

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactListAdapter.ContactHolder>{

    private List<Contact> contactList;
    private Context context;

    private RecyclerItemClickListener recyclerItemClickListener;

    public ContactListAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.contactList = new ArrayList<>();    
    ...

    **public Contact getItem(int position)** {
        return contactList.get(position);
    }
```

Fragment file:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
...
Button btnOK = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
    btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                                      // removeItem() here?
            dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Comment: but you already have `position` in  `onItemLongClick(int position, View view)` as first argument so use that

Comment: just replace 'contactListAdapter.getItem(position)' with 'position'?

Comment: from where you are setting the data in the list Fragment or Activity ??

Comment: if you are passing data list in recyclerview from Fragment they i suggest you to use interface to complete your task

Answer (score 1):

Make your activity to implement View.OnLongClinkListner

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnLongClinkListner {
@Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
int position=(Integer)v.getTag();
        return false;
    }
}



 public void remove(int position){
   adapter.remove(position);
}
```

And in your adapter

```
View.OnLongClinkListner  mLongClickListner;
public ContactListAdapter(Context context) {

 mLongClickListner=(View.OnLongClinkListner)context;
}

@Override
        public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, parent, false);
view.setOnLongClickListner(mLongClickListner);
            return new ContactHolder(view);
        }



@Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ContactHolder holder, final int position) {
... your code;
holder.itemView.setTag(position);
}
```

// to remove item from recycler-view

```
public void removeItem(int position)
{
contactList.remove(position);
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I will try it.  Would the code to launch the DialogFragment be added in your 'public boolean onLongClick section?'

Comment: Yes ```DialogFragment frag=new DialogFragment();
Bundle args=new Bundle();
args.putInt("pos", position);
frag.setArguments(args);```
now show your fragment.

Comment: Ok.  Then how do I reference the item position from the Adapter in the Fragment so that I can add the delete code?

Comment: I have update the code, just call removeItem(position) from your dialog.

Comment: Ok but what code is used in the Fragment to call the removeItem() in the Adapter?

Comment: You may want to do this on click of some button, just paste this there inside.

Comment: Yes, I will edit the above to add the DialogFragment code showing the 'OK' button that should run the removeItem() in the adapter.  I'm just wondering how to get to/reference the Adapter since I don't have much experience with Fragments.

Comment: Pass adapter in argument to fragment constructor or if you are creating it within your activity you can create an instance variable of your adapter and call it directly.

Comment: The adapter is created in the activity.  So do in the Fragment add 'contactlistadaper.removeItem.setTag(position)'?

Comment: Dude create a method activity that calls adapter and call activities method from fragment. ```((YourActivity)getActivity()).remove(position);```

Comment: The adapter is set in the MainActivity.  The removeItem() though is set up in the Adapter file because that is where the ArrayList has all of the model data.  That is why I'm asking how to get the Fragment to run the removeItem() in the Adapter file.

Answer (score 0):

The bundle.putInt function expects an integer in the 2nd argument, you are passing in a 'Contact'. 
Pass 'position' as the 2nd argument instead of 'contactListAdapter.getItem(position)'

Comment: Ok I will try that.  Now  the "fm.setArgments(bundle);" is showing an error: Cannot resolve method.  Any ideas?